# why adding a simple div to HAML will break the code?

Tags: haml

it is quite strange that the following works:

```
- 1.upto(30) do |i|
  = i
  %br
```

but the following won't:

```
%div this line
  - 1.upto(30) do |i|
    = i
    %br
```

Isn't the second part just to add a div and let the numbers go into that div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was the `this line` part intended? Or are you indicating the error position? Because without it, the snippit works.

If `this line` is supposed to be content, then what you want is probably:

```
%div
  this line
  - 1.upto(30) do |i|
    = i
    %br
```

Comment: This is it. Content either goes on the same line, or indented beneath. Not both.

Comment: is that the rule?... i see.  thanks.  anybody know why this rule?  because, without this rule, the code in part 2 of the original post makes sense too... is it to avoid some confusion in some other situation?

Comment: It looks like the syntax is simply defined as either **a)** tag and single line of contents on the same line or **b)** tag, and multiple lines of contents indented. I guess you could compare it to Ruby's two methods of supplying blocks: `do` and `{ }`